# Byte array read from a file and byte array converted from string read from same file differs

Tags: c#

If i read byte array from a file and write it using below code

```
  byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

  File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, byteArr);
```

works perfectly fine.I can open and view the written file properly.

But if i read file contents into a string and then convert it to byte array using below function

```
  string s = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
  var byteArr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
```

the size of byte array is more than the previous array read directly from file and the values are also different, hence if i write the file using this array the cannot be read when opened

**Note:-** File is utf-8 encoded 
i found out that using below code

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            reader.Peek(); // you need this!
            var encoding = reader.CurrentEncoding;
        }
```

Unable to understand why both the array differs??

I was using the below attached image for converting and then writing

[image]

Comment: What do you expect here? Using ReadAlltext() on an image file just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Need to save a file may be anything an image or a text..

Comment: I am uisng filestream to save file data and  need to retrieve file whenever needed

Comment: The short answer is that you can't treat binary data as a string. `ReadAllText` will end up destroying some of the data. It tries to guess an encoding, and what it guesses will depend on the first few bytes of the file. Some byte sequences it encounters may not be representable in a string. It will chop off some bytes that happen to look like carriage returns and newlines.

Comment: You haven't explained why you're trying to use `ReadAllText` instead of `ReadAllBytes`, so it's hard to offer advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8, true))
{
    reader.Peek(); // you need this!
    var encoding = reader.CurrentEncoding;
}
```

your `var encoding` will just echo the  `Encoding.UTF8` parameter. You are deceiving yourself there.

A binary file just has no text encoding.

---

> Need to save a file may be anything an image or a text

Then just use ReadAllBytes/WriteAllBytes. A text file is always also a `byte[]`, but not all file types are text. You would need Base64 encoding first and that just adds to the size.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to convert byte arrays to strings is indeed encoding it in something like base64.
Like:

string s= Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);